# Cannot get Outlook application object to work

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I'm trying to write a program that lists the members of an Outlook email distribution list.

I've found that VBA seems to have objects that could make this possible, but I haven't yet been able to get it to work.  I've studied [this Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-object-outlook) on the Outlook Application object, [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getdefaultfolder-method-outlook) about the `GetDefaultFolder` method, and many other reference materials, and have come up with the following program:

```
Set Application = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) 
myFolder.Display
```

However, when I run this using wscript or cscript I get the following:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument:
>   'myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder'

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code is not working it because when you are accessing a library with late binding, e.g. by using `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`, the enumerations built into the library are not available.

Since you haven't used the `Option Explicit` directive, Excel has automatically declared `olFolderContacts` as a variable of type Variant with a value of `Empty`. *That* is the invalid argument that the error message is referring to.

If you wish to continue using late binding, either add the following code so the constants are available:

```
  'v0.1.1
  ' Required if late binding Outlook
  ' (Note that this list excludes newer values available in Outlook 2010 or later)
  Private Enum OlDefaultFolders
    olFolderDeletedItems = ------------3
    olFolderOutbox = ------------------4
    olFolderSentMail = ----------------5
    olFolderInbox = ------------------(6)
    olFolderCalendar = ----------------9
    olFolderContacts = --------------(10)
    olFolderJournal = ----------------11
    olFolderNotes = ------------------12
    olFolderTasks = ------------------13
    olFolderDrafts = ----------------(16)
    olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders = 18
    olFolderConflicts = --------------19
    olFolderSyncIssues = ------------(20)
    olFolderLocalFailures = ----------21
    olFolderServerFailures = --------(22)
    olFolderJunk = ------------------(23)
    olFolderRssFeeds = --------------(25)
    olFolderToDo = ------------------(28)
    olFolderManagedEmail = ----------(29)
  End Enum
```

or hard-code the values:

```
'v0.1.0
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(10)
myFolder.Display
```

Note that I've changed the name of the variable for the Outlook Application object so as to avoid any confusion with the built-in `Application` object.

I find it better, at least while developing the code, to use early binding. You do this by adding a reference to the Outlook object library to the project:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

and using the following code:

```
'v0.1.0
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Set myNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
myFolder.Display
```

---

A final tip is to always use the `Option Explicit` directive, and always explicitly declare all your variables.

The best way to ensure this happens is to set the `Require Variable Declaration` option:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

That way the VBE will always insert the directive in every module created.

Comment: Excellent answer!  I used the four-line example you provided after sayhing "or hard code the values" and it worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @fireblood You're welcome. Don't forget, you can also upvote any/all answers, including accepted ones, by clicking on the upwards pointing grey triangle at the top-left of the answer. You can also upvote any question you find useful too.

Comment: Well-done answer, I upvoted.  I'm almost certain that this will help my accounting app (VB6) which recently started failing with its Outlook contacts interface.  I'd searched for solutions before but couldn't find any documentation on the issue this well-explained.  I'd give this 100 upvotes if I could.

Comment: @BillHileman You know, you can always drop a bounty on any question, and award it to any answer to that question ;-) (The question has to be at least two days old before you can do that, though :-( )

Comment: I've verified the code I use is essentially identical to your example, except that my reference is for version 16, not 12.  That's probably my issue.  I'm getting the activeX can't create object error.  From memory, MS just says that "it happens" on some machines, sigh.  create object returns the same error.  Not a huge deal for me, but I might pursue it further one day.  Thanks for the offer.

Comment: @BillHileman Interesting. When testing for the solution, I managed the get that precise error once. Not sure what I did to get it. Might try a little mmore investigation. As for the the version, yeah, I thought about mentioning that in the answer, but figured it would be obvious enough. It depends on the version of MS Office that's installed. You just use whichever one is there (12 = Excel 2007; 16 = Excel 2016 - there is a jump from 12 to 14 when going from 2007 to 2010, not sure why, though.)

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with one of the recent security updates from MS?  I'm not really sure when the problem presented itself.  My customer base is small, and I don't know that any of my customers have even used the export to contacts options that I've added years ago - and perhaps they're not even having the same problem I am.  I only discovered the problem because out of boredom I've been jazzing-up and modernizing the user interface and noticed it no longer seemed to work while testing my UI changes.

Comment: @BillHileman Definitely not in my case. Was testing on an old Vista laptop running MS Office 2007 ;-) I tried re-creating the activeX error, but couldn't manage to. I'll have to let it stew to see if I can recall exactly what I did.

Comment: @robinCTS I think I may have found out why I am having problems based on the following post: [StackOverflow VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064636/outlook-redemption-error-in-ms-access-activex-component-cant-create-object).  Check out the offered answer, I think it applies in my case since VB6 is 32-bit and I'm fairly sure my Office 2016 is 64-bit

Comment: @BillHileman Ah. Interesting find. Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried to use
Set OA = Outlook.Application
to replace
Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

I am using Microsoft Office 365 and Outlook 365 system.  And it works.